# Simple bitcoin mining algorithm

Tags: c#, c, algorithm, bitcoin

I'm trying to figure out how does simple Bitcoin mining algorithm works in plain simple c or c#  or some pseudo language. I've found an example at http://pastebin.com/EXDsRbYH, but unfortunately It isn't clear what it does. I was unable to run it.

Suppose I have only one input: a Bitcoin wallet "abc..." which I would like to be used for the Bitcoins to be mined. I need simple to understand algorithm that will do the bitcoin mining on one machine with one thread on one cpu [I know it will take ages to complete :)]

Comment: I am not sure about this but maybe [this thread](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=49657.0) may help?

Comment: Thanks, I will try to ask at bitcoin

Comment: @Lu4 Did you make any progress with mining with c#

Comment: I have the idea but don't have time to implement it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Super-dumb and rather useless, but  I did this one for demo purposes once:

```
from hashlib import md5
from random import random
import sys

# what to hash
data = "Bitcoins!"

# This is just a first run to init the variables 
h = md5(data.encode('utf-8'))
v = h.digest()
best = v
best_i = data
best_vhex = h.hexdigest()

# x ist just a helper to only display
# a subset of all updates (calculates faster)
x = 0
step = 100

# In reality, this loop stops when the "h" hash
# is below a certain threshold (called "difficulty")
while True:
  i = data + str(random())
  h = md5(i.encode('utf-8'))
  v = h.digest()
  vhex = h.hexdigest()

  # log progress
  if v < best or x > step:
    msg = "%-25s | %-25s -> %s" % (i, best_i, best_vhex)
    sys.stdout.write('\r' + msg)
    x = 0
  else:
    x += 1

  # check if new best one
  if v < best:
    best_i, best, best_vhex = i, v, vhex
    print
```

Comment: Why are you using MD5? I understand bitcoin mining must be done with SHA256... or?

Comment: why is this super dumb and useless ? I'm sorry, but i really don't know much about bitcoin, and was looking for some source code (in any language), that I could use to understand what the mining algorithm actually is..

Comment: In this code, when would a block be output? trying to educate myself...

Comment: This code sample only demonstrates how to process a block. There is no output. 
You need additional code to "construct" the block (Pick the most jucy transactions and wrap them into the block etc...)  and then to submit it. It only shows the core "issue" by demonstrating how the proof of work works. You proof is finding a block (transactions) + random message that produces a has smaller than the difficulty.